# I want to change logo text color when the page scrolls down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating the parallax website. The problem I'm facing is that when the page scrolls down its wont change the color of the logo I wanna make it blue when the page scrolls down. Its default color is white now. I don't know how to fix it.

The code down here is the nav code when the page scrolls down I want to change logo color when it scrolls down.

```
var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('.navbar-default').css({
      "background": "#fff"
    });
  } else {
    $('.navbardefault').css({
      "background": "transparent"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Is your logo an image?

Comment: Just as a note: you should *never* listen to the scroll event. You might check this article about parllax scrolling [Parallax Done Right](https://medium.com/@dhg/parallax-done-right-82ced812e61c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that could be your issue is that typo in your class name near the end (`.navbardefault`).  When fixed I see what I assume is your intended behavior.

```js
var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('.navbar-default').css({
      "background": "#fff"
    });
  } else {
    $('.navbar-default').css({
      "background": "transparent"
    }).removeClass('after-scroll-nav-border');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: red;
  height: 600px;
}
.navbar-default {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="navbar-default">Nav Bar</a>
```