# Link color not changing with parallax scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a parallax website which has a nav. When the page scrolls down, the nav changes its color. Bow when the page loads the navigation background color is transparent and when the page scrolls down it turns into white.

The links are meant to have color `#BBB9BE` and hover color `#3F4474` on the white background color, but it's showing the same color and hover color on the transparent background, which means my else statement is not working properly. What's the issue here?

```
var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
    $('.navbar-default').css({ "background": "#fff" }).addClass('after-scroll- nav-border');

    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus ').hover(function() {
      $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus ').css({ "color": "#3F4474" });
    }, function() {
      $(".navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus").css({ "color": "#BBB9BE" });
    });
  } else {
    $('.navbar-default').css({ "background": "transparent" }).removeClass('after-scroll-nav-border');

    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus ').hover(function() {
      $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus ').css({ "color": "#fff" });
    }, function() {
      $(".navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus").css({ "color": "#BBB9BE" });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to change logo text color when the page scrolls down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524242/i-want-to-change-logo-text-color-when-the-page-scrolls-down)

Comment: One thing is you are creating new hover event listeners every time the scroll event listener is triggered. That might not be the actual issue causing your problem, but it will probably cause some kind of problem at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some words in your question so I'm not sure if I understand completely. Firstly, there's a space between `after-scroll- nav-border`, this might be your problem. And as another commented mentioned, you're creating the `.hover()` event every time the page scrolls.

Secondly, instead of using `.hover()` have you considered using a pure CSS solution? Something like this:

JS

```
var a = $(".navbar-default").offset().top;
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 10)
    {
      $('.navbar-default').addClass('after-scroll-nav-border');
    }
    else
    {
      $('.navbar-default').removeClass('after-scroll-nav-border');
    }
  }
```

CSS

```
.navbar-default {
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default.after-scroll-nav-border {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #bbb9be;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default.after-scroll-nav-border .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, 
.navbar-default.after-scroll-nav-border .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #3f4474;
}
```

On page load the default styles will be used (`#bbb9be` text, `#ffffff` hover). You're already adding a class of `after-scroll-nav-border`once the page is scrolled past 10, so by creating another set of styles rooted on that class you get your desired colour changes without any unnecessary JS.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: thanks sir i already tried this  but when the page scrolled after 10 i want the link color to be #bbb9be and the hover color #3f4474 i'm stuck at this stage. i dont want the default hover link color like we did on the transparent background color

Comment: @danialpervaiz Sorry, I'm confused. The code I wrote above sets the link color to #bbb9be and hover colour to #3f4474 after 10 just like you mentioned. Is there something I missed?

Comment: yeah its working perfectly but before 10 i want to make hover color #fff .